# How to web scrape information that is inside a dictionary which is inside a list

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to web scrape the prices of a games console. In the HTML code you can see that `price` is a value of the dictionary `product_price`.

```py
import requests, webbrowser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://www.idealo.co.uk/compare/200637075/microsoft-xbox-series-s.html')

price_checker = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

# class = class="productOffers-listItemOfferPrice"
price = price_checker.find_all(class_="productOffers-listItemOfferPrice" )
```

Instead of getting the price, however, I get this output:

```
<strike>[<a class="productOffers-listItemOfferPrice" data-gtm-event="transaction.leadout" data-gtm-payload='{"event_action": "price.leadout", "event_label": "offerlist", "column": "price", "event_category": "transaction",
                "product_id": "200637075",
                "product_name": "Microsoft Xbox Series S",
                "product_price": "232.59",
                "product_category": "3189",
                "currency": "GBP",
                "shop_name": "shopplayuk",
                "delivery_time": "medium",
                "shop_rating": "100",
                "position": "1",
                "free_return": "0",
                "offer_segment": "new",
                "approved_shipping": "false",
                "voucher": "false"}' href="/go/3411999890895798527.html?categoryId=3189&amp;offerKey=16a7543b180924afe8cea4fc9985ad72&amp;offerListId=200637075-59E5136D65A4784386E4CC21644AD169&amp;pos=1&amp;price=232.59&amp;productid=200637075&amp;sid=22818&amp;type=offer" rel="noopener nofollow" target="_blank"></strike>
```

How do you extract it from inside a dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `json` module to parse the attribute:

```py
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Gets the website we want.
res = requests.get(
    "https://www.idealo.co.uk/compare/200637075/microsoft-xbox-series-s.html"
)

price_checker = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")

price = price_checker.find(class_="productOffers-listItemOfferPrice")
data = json.loads(price["data-gtm-payload"])

# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print(data["product_price"], data["currency"])
```

Prints:

```
232.59 GBP
```